# Swift Function to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've been trying to convert this Swift function to Objective-C for so long. Someone please help.

It's a function that centers SpriteKit nodes at the right location on all devices.

```
func convert(point: CGPoint)->CGPoint {
    return self.view!.convertPoint(CGPoint(x: point.x, y:self.view!.frame.height-point.y), toScene:self)
}
```

Guess this is a good time to learn Swift.

Comment: convertPoint and self.view!

Comment: Forget the Swift code. How would you write a simple method in Objective-C that takes a `CGPoint` and returns another `CGPoint`?

Comment: -(void)random:(CGPoint)point{

Comment: -(CGPoint)   sorry hit enter

Comment: Why dont you do something like this we just need to return the cgpoint   return CGPoint(point.x, self.view!.frame.height-point.y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CGPoint) convertPoint: (CGPoint) point {
    return [self.view convertPoint: CGPointMake(point.x, self.view.frame.size.height - point.y) toScene: self];
}
```